# Haskell - cycling through list to map new lists

Tags: haskell

I'm working on a beginner Haskell program that can take a database of product prices (i.e. a price list) and a list of barcodes of the items in a shopping cart and generate the list of item prices. But the code that I've written produces type errors that I'll go into below. First, my code:

I begin by defining my relevant types:

```
type BarCode = Int
type Name = String
type Price = Int
type PriceList = [(BarCode,Name,Price)]
type CartItems = [BarCode]
type CartPrices = [(Name,Price)]
```

Next, I started to write my main program:

```
priceCart :: PriceList -> CartItems -> CartPrices
priceCart ((bc, n, p):xs) (b:bs) = map look (xs b)

look :: PriceList -> BarCode -> (Name, Price)
look [] barcode = ("None",0)
look ((bc, n, p):xs) barcode
    | bc == barcode = (n, p)
    | otherwise = look xs barcode
```

Essentially, I want to be able to go through my list of barcodes and call my `look` function for every element of `CartItems` and build a list with the `map` function. But my knowledge doesn't quite extend to all of the prelude functions, and so I believe I'm using the `map` function incorrectly. In fact, I know this, because of the compile errors that I got (see below). But now I'm also wondering if I'm missing how to correctly iterate through my list in `priceCart` -- should I perhaps be using recursion as in my `look` function? If so, I'm a little confused as to how I can combine all of the aforementioned functions to produce the desired output.

[image: Compile Errors]

Comment: What is `xs b` doing here?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I was trying to send my PriceList (xs) and the first element of my list (b) into the `look` function to "look up" the corresponding tuple of (Name, Price).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to look up each `BarCode` in the `PriceList`.  I expect that the result of `priceList` will be the same length as the input `CartItems`.  This is a good fit for `map`.

In general, `map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`.
In your case, you want `map :: (BarCode -> (Name, Price)) -> [BarCode] -> [(Name, Price)]`.

You have a list of type `[Barcode]`, so that's no problem.  You *almost* have a function of type `BarCode -> (Name, Price)` in `look :: PriceList -> BarCode -> (Name, Price)`.  The key point is that you will compare each `BarCode` to the same `PriceList`.  So you can write `priceCart prices bs = map (look prices) bs`, where `look prices :: BarCode -> (Name, Price)`.

Partial application often trips up people learning Haskell.  `look prices` is equivalent to `\barcode -> look prices barcode` in anonymous-function syntax.  `prices` supplies the first argument to `look`, and what's left is a function that still needs a `BarCode`.

You can use explicit recursion anywhere that you can use `map` - explicit recursion is more general.  In this case, I find the version with `map` easier to read.

Answer (score 2):

What i think you are looking for is to look `PriceList` with the first element in the `CartItems`, then look the `PriceList` with the second element in the `CartItems` and so forth. This can be done with recursion, building a list like this

```
priceCart :: PriceList -> CartItems -> CartPrices
priceCart [] _ = []
priceCart t@((bc, n, p):xs) (b:bs) = look t b : priceCart t bs
```

As you see the pattern matching on PriceList is not of use and could be replaced:

```
priceCart t (b:bs) = look t b : priceCart t bs
```

Why is this not working with `map` in the way you have written in this case?

So map is looking for a function to apply on every element in the input list. Your function takes two arguments, one of the arguments can be found as an element in PriceList, namely `xs`. The other argument however, `b (BarCode)`, is NOT an element in your list `xs`, and `map` will not be able to recognize it as one of the arguments for the functions, since it is not an element in the list that you are mapping on.